# Position independent code, shared libraries and code veneers - getting them to work together

Tags: c, arm, shared-libraries

I'm developing for an embedded platform and I'm having a hard time working out how to link shared libraries dynamically. I'm using the bFLT file format and I don't have control over where the executable and shared library is loaded.

My loader correctly loads the shared library and executable into memory and modifies the executable's GOT at run time to link to the shared library.

I can successfully take the address of the function and I know it's correct from disassembling the code at that location. However, if I try to call the function, the whole thing crashes.

Turns out GCC adds a 'code veneer' when calling shared library functions and takes a detour when the function is called and doesn't actually branch to the address of the function. The address that the code veneer branches to isn't relocated properly because it doesn't show up in the list of relocations in the executable binary.

The disassembly of the veneer looks like this:

```
000008d0 <__library_call_veneer>:
 8d0:   e51ff004    ldr pc, [pc, #-4]   ; 8d4 <__library_call_veneer+0x4>
 8d4:   03000320    .word   0x03000320  ; This address isn't correctly relocated!
```

If I take the address of the function and put it into a function pointer (therefore, bypassing the 'code veneer') and call it, the shared library works perfectly.

So for example:

```
#define DIRECT_LIB_CALL(x, args...) do { \
        typeof(x) * volatile tmp = x; \
        tmp(#args); \
    } while (0)

DIRECT_LIB_CALL(library_call); /* works */
library_call(); /* crashes */
```

Is there a way to either, tell GCC to not produce a code veneer and branch directly to the address located in the GOT or somehow make the address that the code veneer branches show up in the list of relocations to perform?

Comment: Are you declaring the library's prototypes using extern C?

Comment: I'm compiling under C so extern "C" would be redundant wouldn't it?

Comment: Veneers are more-or-less needed on ARM systems, making the veneer is the right thing to do. However, not updating the address is not... Looking at your file format, http://docs.blackfin.uclinux.org/doku.php?id=toolchain:executable_file_formats and http://docs.blackfin.uclinux.org/doku.php?id=toolchain:creating_libraries come up. It looks like you may have a conflicting shared library ID, or you may want to modify your linking flags (as explained there). Sorry can't help much more

Comment: Well, I suppose I can help a bit more. On an ARM system, veneers are created because a branch can only be 16mb (or 4MB Thumb) or especially are needed if Thumb/ARM is mixed. The veneer will change it to the proper mode and load the PC directly, instead of performing the branch, thereby allowing a jump of more than 16mb/4mb. You shouldn't look at disabling veneers, but rather, making your loader rewrite them properly. If that's impossible then I'm not sure you *can* stop GCC from generating them, not as far as I can determine in the time I have.

Comment: Addendum: check out http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/ARM-Options.html, specifically, -mno-long-calls . It looks like you can use a #pragma to disable the veneers.

Comment: @OrgnlDave, it seems that -mno-long-calls will have no effect on weak function declarations which is basically what this is so it's a dead end there. Looks like I'll have to find another way to tackle this problem.

Comment: Is GCC the vendor's recommended toolchain? Does it work with any other compiler?

Comment: It's a homebrew SDK so there isn't really an official toolchain.

Comment: Did you try the #pragma blocks instead of just -mno-long-calls ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround to this problem. It's not the best or cleanest method but it does the job in my case.

I took advantage of the `--wrap` option in my linker which redirects symbols to `__wrap_symbol`. With this, I set up a awk script that automatically generates ASM files that load a properly relocated address into the pc. Any library calls would be redirected to this code. Basically what I did was make my own code veneers. Since the generated code veneer wasn't being referenced, it simply got optimized away.

Additionally, I had to place my veneers in the .data section since anything in the .text section was not relocated correctly. Since, the platform I'm working on doesn't differentiate between code and data that much, this hacky workaround works.

[Here's a link](https://github.com/tangrs/ndless-bflt-loader/tree/master/shared_library_test) to the project I'm working on where you can look up the specifics.

Comment: Good job. I would submit a feature request to the homebrew SDK authors to add proper veneer support...it's a fairly basic thing for ARM platforms because of the limitations of branching...